# pandas filling gaps of missing data

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas DataFrames

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4]},
               index=[['A',  'A', 'B', 'B'], [1, 2, 1, 2]])

>>> df1
     a   b
A 1  1 NaN
  2  2 NaN
B 1  3   3
  2  4   4
```

and

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': [1, 2]}, index=[['A','A'], [1, 2]])
>>> df2

     b
A 1  1
  2  2
```

where df2 contains the missing data of df1. How can I merge the two DataFrames to get

```
     a   b
A 1  1   1
  2  2   2
B 1  3   3
  2  4   4
```

? I tried `pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)`  which results in

```
     a   b   b
A 1  1 NaN   1
  2  2 NaN   2
B 1  3   3 NaN
  2  4   4 NaN
```

In my case it is guaranteed that I have no overlapping values.

Comment: You can try `df1.combine_first(df2)` or `df1.fillna(df2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

```
print df1.combine_first(df2)
     a  b
A 1  1  1
  2  2  2
B 1  3  3
  2  4  4

print df1.fillna(df2) 
     a  b
A 1  1  1
  2  2  2
B 1  3  3
  2  4  4
```

Timing:

```
In [5]: %timeit df1.combine_first(df2)
The slowest run took 6.01 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.15 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit df1.fillna(df2)
The slowest run took 5.23 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.76 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `update`:

```
In [36]: df1.update(df2)

In [37]: df1
Out[37]:
     a  b
A 1  1  1
  2  2  2
B 1  3  3
  2  4  4
```